# Draw shiny lights in OpenGL to simulate a old monitor scanline

Tags: opengl

I'm writing a terminal emulator that simulates the look of a old monitor ([software link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/vinterm)). Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

For this version, I use 2D graphics. My intention is to migrate to OpenGL to achieve higher perfomance and to be able to have a screen curvature, such as this:

[Screenshot 2 http://www.meeho.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Cathode.png](http://www.meeho.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/Cathode.png)

To achieve a higher realism, I want to draw the scanlines individually. This way, it would look something like this when greatly amplified:

[image: Shot 3]

So my question is: what would be the best strategy to achieve this (that is, draw these grainy shiny lights over a curved surface with a high framerate) with OpenGL?

Comment: Just do it in a shader. Have some sine function affect the brightness of your screen's "lines" or something similar like that.

Answer (score 1):

I should point out that not all terminals had [shadow mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mask) CRTs (which was responsible for the bulge). Higher end terminals had (relatively) flat [aperture grille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_grille) CRTs. On the other extreme, really cheap terminals had somewhat annoying scrolling horizontal bars.

My fondest memories are programming on a SONY Trinitron terminal, which didn't have issues with brightness on horizontal scan lines, but did have a very pronounced vertical pitch between pixels.

Here's what things looked like on aperture grille CRTs:

[image]

- I haven't seen any CRT emulating shaders that ever replicate this though.

To me, there's more than one way to skin a CRT... you might want to emulate a dot matrix grid, darken alternate fields, have a horizontal line that slowly scrolls up/down the screen, apply a pincushion distortion to simulate non-flat CRTs.

In any case, don't think of this as drawing lights. Draw the basic text into an FBO and then modulate the luminance of each pixel and apply the pincushion distortion in a fragment shader.

To achieve the effect in your final screenshot, you are going to need more than scanlines. You will also have to simulate the shadow mask dot matrix, you can probably do this with a simple texture.